# AWS Workmail and SES Dedicated IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

Do you know when we get a dedicated IP address on AWS for SES, this IP address we will also be used in the Workmail?

Comment: I greatly doubt it. Those are two different services, and Amazon SES is all about maintaining the reputation of the IP address. Does it matter to you if the IP addresses are different?

Comment: Really?  I use workmail.  the server ip address is listed in the SORBS blacklist.  How can I send from workmail and make sure that it uses the dedicated (managed) IP address I set up?  Anyone know of a tutorial?